# Dart: determining the size (innerWidth) of a img tag

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am developing a simple polymer dart application and I have a polymer tag containing an image tag

```dart
<polymer-element name="picasa-photo">
  <template>
      <img  src="{{imageUrl}}" width="100%">
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="picasaphoto.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The width is set to 100% so that the image will resize when the user resizes the browser.

At regular intervals I change the {{imageUrl}} property to download a photo from google's picassa web site. The picassa web site API allows me to specify the resolution of the image that is downloaded and I would like to match it to the current size of the image. For example, if the user makes the browser very large, then I would like to download a high resolution image. Likewise if the browser is very small, I can get Picasso to download a small image.

My question is, how can I determine the actual size of the image tag?

Comment: If I was using JQuery I would find the element and then use its innerWidth and innerHeight elements, and I see that the Element object returned by the querySelector() has a clientHeight and clientWidth which all looks hopeful, but I am creating a Polymer element I dont think I have control of the tags id.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have control about the tags id.  The only difference is, that the id of the img tag is only valid inside the custom element. You can use `shadowRoot.querySelector('#id').innerWidth;` or the shortcut `$['id'].innerWidth;`
It's also possible to access it from outside your custom element  with `document.querySelector('#custElmId`).shadowRoot.querySelector('#id').innerWidth;`